# Return a list of characters from a mixed list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a Lisp function to return a list of characters (no repeats) from a list (with ints, characters, etc). I'm still a beginner with Lisp and am having trouble starting. Our prof mentioned using atom but I can't figure out what she meant. Here is the question:

"Write a lisp function that accepts a list as the input argument (the list is mixed up integers, decimals,
characters and nested lists) and creates a list including all the characters in the original list without any
duplication. Sample program output is shown below:

1. ‘((z f) (b a 5 3.5) 6 (7) (a) c) -> (z f b a c)
2. ‘( (n) 2 (6 h 7.8) (w f) (n) (c) n) -> (h w f c n) "

Comment: The examples do not contain any characters. They contain some symbols; those symbols have names which are character strings of length one. The character `A` is coded in (ANSI Common) Lisp syntax as `#\A`. Hash backslash A.

Comment: In Lisp, there is no "decimal" type. `3.5` is a token representing a *floating-point* number. The printed notation is decimal, but floating-point numbers aren't decimal internally. Sometimes new programmers do numeric work believing that floating-point numbers are decimal; then they are surprised when the results don't obey pencil-and-paper decimal arithmetic.

Comment: `atom` is a function that returns `t` (true) if it's argument is not a (non-empty) list. Thus, when traversing a list it can be used to determine if the current element is something that should be considered for collecting (unless already seen), or if it is a sublist that itself should be traversed.

Answer (score 2):

What your assignment calls “characters” are actually symbols with a name of length 1.  It seems that you can just mentally replace the word “characters” with “symbols” and work with this.

An atom is anything that is not a cons—any non-empty list consists of a chain of conses.  For example, symbols, numbers, strings, and `nil` are atoms.

A cons (actually a cons cell) is a simple datastructure that can hold two things.  In a list, the first thing of each cons is some list element, and the second either a pointer to the next cons or nil.  You can also have lists as list elements; then also the first thing would be a pointer to a list.  This would then formally be a tree.  The accessor function for the first thing of a cons is called `car` or `first`, the accessor function for the other thing is called `cdr` or `rest`.  `Car` and `cdr` are a bit archaic, and mainly used when you see the cons cell as a tree node, while `first` and `rest` are more modern, and mainly used when you see the cons cell as a list chain link.

You can test whether a thing is an atom with the function `atom`.  If it is not an atom, it is a list with at least one element.

Your assignment has a few parts:

- Walk the tree to look at each element.  This can be done through recursion, or through looping in one direction and recursing in the other.
- Keep a list of symbols that you already found.
- If the element you look at is a symbol (with a name of length 1…), then check whether it is new, if yes, add it to your list.
- Finally return that list.

One useful idiom is to use `push` or `pushnew`, which put new elements at the front of the list, and at the end `reverse` it.

Comment: I don't want to spoil the homework but could you give an example of how to update and return the resulting list within recursion. Somehow in my insufficient attempt, I get always `nil` even if `trace` shows that the correct atoms are found.

Comment: When the function is called recursively with a subtree, it will return a list of symbols only from that subtree.  You need to combine this with the list of the current level, e. g. through `append` and `remove-duplicates`.

Comment: That means that the `pushnew` approach only works in an iterative solution?

Comment: It modifies a place, so it only makes sense when you have some place accessible from more than one recursive invocation.  One approach would be to have an inner function to do the recursion.

Comment: Of course, you can also first flatten, then filter, then remove duplicates.